# Sagemaker Studio domain creation: possible to mount a previous EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

In order to change some settings, there is currently a need to recreate the domain. However, I have an existing EFS that I would like to retain. Is it possible to remount this EFS directory to the new domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to attach an existing EFS to a new domain. If you have multiple users and data, I'd recommend the steps in the [Backup and recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/sagemaker-studio-admin-best-practices/appendix.html#studio-domain-backup-and-recovery) section here.

If it is only a handful user profiles, you can simply download the files/use S3 as an intermediate storage.